# Selenium : Converting List<WebElement> to Set<String>

Tags: java, selenium

I want to get a unique elements from the page. I'am calculating total number of records. Each record belong to a user, hence there are multiple records with the belongs to the same user. I want to get the total with the unique number of users.

```
List<WebElement> efirstpagecount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='usersList']/tbody/tr/td[3]"));

Set<WebElement> uniquecount = new HashSet<WebElement>(efirstpagecount);
System.out.println("Unique count: " + uniquecount.size());

for (WebElement u : uniquecount ) {
  System.out.println(u.getText());
  }
```

Output:

```
Unique count: 20
robin
Rocky
prom
jack
stone
Veronica
Veronica
Shawn
Rocky
carl
Rocky
James
Rocky
sam
bon
sam
bone
don
Shawn
don
```

Above code is giving me the the count including the duplicate values. Please advise how to get the unique values. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the `Set` has duplicates (keys)? Can you show the output provided by your code?

Comment: you may need different logic to get the unique user records.  elements are always unique only even though it is duplicate text value. please share your html code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the td just has the username, you can try something like this in java 8.

```
    Set<String> uniqueUsers = efirstpagecount.stream()
            .map(WebElement::getText).map(String::trim)
            .distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: It worked. But I have one query here. There are say 100 pages in my application. 10 records are displayed each page. I want to get the user only once is he appears across all the pages. So for example for user "Nick" I found an entry while executing script, then the second time if "Nick" appears in later pages then it should get skipped and excluded from the total count. Is is feasible?